# Logging out from Facebook connected Android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, facebook-login

So i followed the instructions on logging to an Android app using Facebook from the [Androidhive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) (Most of the classes used here are deprecated, i know) and ended up with this as my MainActivity

```
package com.divingscores;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static String APP_ID = "779458385402636";

Intent facebookLogoutIntent = new Intent(this, LogoutActivity.class);
private Button fbLoginButton;

private Facebook facebook;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    //mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                                           }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }



                });
}}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    fbLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbLoginButton);
    fbLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()) {


  case R.id.fbLoginButton:
      loginToFacebook();
      break;
  }

}
}
```

Everything works fine and I am able to login to the app.But the problem is i stay logged in and since i did not specify what the app should do the `emulator`does not start.I want to be able to start an `activity`when login is successful but am not sure where I should put the code to do this.

Comment: Why not use Sessions to connect to facebook ?

Comment: I can't find any tutorials on that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with connecting Facebook on Android using the Sessions objects.

> Pre:  Import the Facebook SDK to your project.

1. First create a method `setupFacebookConnect()` in your Activity where you want to use Facebook login

   ```
   // Add the Session status variable to your activity
   private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new FBSessionStatus();

   /**
   *
   * @param Bundle
   *
   */
   public void setupFacebookConnect(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

       Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                   savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                   .setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement the `onStart`, `onStop`, `onSavedInstanceState` and `onActivityResult` methods of activity as given below

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       Session.saveSession(session, outState);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
           resultCode, data);
   }
   ```
3. Add an inner class in the Activity to listen for Session status callbacks as

   ```
   private class FBSessionStatus implements Session.StatusCallback {

       @Override
       public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
           Exception exception) {

       }
   }
   ```
4. Add to your manifest

   ```
   <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
   </activity>
   ```

   and the permission to access Internet

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```

   and the Facebook application id

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
       android:value="APP_ID" />
   ```
5. Now create a method `connectFacebook()` which you may call to connect to Facebook

   ```
   public void connectFacebook() {
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
           session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
               .setCallback(statusCallback));
       } else {
           Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
       }
   }
   ```
6. Atlast create a method `disConnectFacebook` to be called when you want to disconnect and clear the session

   ```
   public void disConnectFacebook() {
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       if (!session.isClosed()) {
           session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
       }
   }
   ```
7. Now, with everything set up in right place call `setupFacebookConnect()` method from `onCreate()` of the Activity. You may call the `connectFacebook()` and `disConnectFacebook()` at places where you want to connect or disconnect, like on button press, or in some dialog, anywhere you want.

> Pheww !! that was long, I hope it works, I have tested the connect and
>   disconnect.

You can see the whole source code here https://gist.github.com/rachitrm/7978389 or branch this repository https://github.com/rachitrm/rm-facebook-login

Comment: This looks great.So how do i call this 

`disconnectFacebook();`

method?

Comment: Whenever you want to disConnect(), just call this method, from anywhere you want, in the Activity.

Comment: I understand that.But going by your suggested code where do i place the call to a new activity?

Comment: call setupFacebook connect from onCreate(), and call connectFacebook when the Facebook Login button is pressed. see step 8.

Comment: There is an error in the code you posted.It says

 `FBSessionStatus()`

cannot be resolved to a type.Can you check the code in your IDE and see what's wrong please?

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu see the updated answer for source. accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks mate but there seem to be an error which i have started a new thread for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600929/error-connecting-to-android-app-through-facebook-session)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43221/discussion-between-ojonugwa-ochalifu-and-twntee)